# Using copy function to deploy application in multiple regions ARM template

Tags: azure, azure-rm-template

I am trying to deploy some resources in multiple regions using copy() function.
The template was works fine when being deployed in single region but as aI add copy function and use concat to give resource new name the copyindex doesnt work

Comment: Are you using VS code or Visual studio or In Azure portal?

Comment: @RithwikBojja using VS Code

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce the issue and got the expected result, and I followed the below steps:

1. Open VS code and click on file and create a new File With `json`  Format

From the referenced link use the  `parameters`  &  `resources`  code in the below json file.

***.json file:***

```
{
"$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
"contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
"parameters": {
"regions": {
"type": "array",
"defaultValue": [
{
"location": "WestUS",
"prefix": "appserver-1"
},
{
"location": "EastUS",
"prefix": "appserver-2"
}
],
"metadata": {
"description": "Locations"
}
}
},
"functions": [],
"variables": {},
"resources": [
{
"apiVersion": "2015-08-01",
"copy" : {
"name": "regionCopy",
"count": "[length(parameters('regions'))]"
},
"name": "[concat('abc-', parameters('regions')[copyIndex()].prefix, '')]",
"type": "Microsoft.Web/serverfarms",
"location": "[parameters('regions')[copyIndex()].location]",
"sku": {
"name": "F1"
},
"properties": {
}
}
],

"outputs": {}
}
```

Select the parameters file like below:

[image]

And select  **New**  option shown in the below pic:  [image]

And select  **All parameters**  shown in the below pic:  ][image]

Save the parameter file in the same location where the first  **.json**  format application has saved before. After that  **deploying to Azure portal**  open terminal and follow the below commands one by one.

**login to Azure portal :**

```
az login
```

[image]
**Create a resource group:**

```
 az group create --name resource-group-name --location location-name
```

[image]

**Depoly into the created azure resource group:**

```
az deployment group create --resource-group ResourceGroupName --template-file filename.json --parameters filaname.parameters.json
```

[image]
After successfully executed.

Go to the azure portal and search for resource group you have created for this one, you will find the servers like below,

[image]

Thanks to  `@Toon`, followed his  [document](https://yourazurecoach.com/2019/12/10/multi-region-arm-deployments/)  and reproduced for the same above requirement.